# TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined at onFormSubmit(Code:34)

Tags: javascript

This is supposed to send an email based on a form. However, no email gets sent and this error pops up:

> TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined.

I've bolded (**) the line that's producing the error. Note that I have no coding experience so try and explain what I should do using basic terms.
at `onFormSubmit(Code:34)`

````
  var responses = e.namedValues;

  // If the question title is a label, it can be accessed as an object field.
  // If it has spaces or other characters, it can be accessed as a dictionary.
  var timestamp = responses.Timestamp[0];
  **var email = responses['Email Address'][0].trim();**
  var name = responses.Name[0].trim();
  var topicsString = responses.Topics[0].toLowerCase();

  // Parse topics of interest into a list (since there are multiple items
  // that are saved in the row as blob of text).
  var topics = Object.keys(topicUrls).filter(function(topic) {
    // indexOf searches for the topic in topicsString and returns a non-negative
    // index if the topic is found, or it will return -1 if it's not found.
    return topicsString.indexOf(topic.toLowerCase()) != -1;
  });```
````

Comment: The error means there's no `Email Address` property in the `responses` object.

Comment: Use `console.log(responses)` to see what the correct property name is.

Comment: Figured out that the issue was because I had "Email address" in the response form and "Email Address" in the code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `responses['Email Address']` is null/undefined.

The best way to resolve this is to inspect your `response` and see what the object looks like. If you paste your full response snippet, I can answer you question better. Without knowing what that object looks like, it's hard to provide you with an exact answer.

If you are unsure how to figure out what the object is, you can always log it out to the console by doing `console.log(response)`

Here is an example of what is happening:

```js
const nothing = undefined;
console.log(nothing[0]);
```

Happy to update my answer when you post what the `response` object looks like.

Comment: So do I copy that console.log(response) into the code and run it? The "Email address" is supposed to link to a google form and google sheets document https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdstIDwIHCwKZhpxgBkM6DrH-KAuEkBuNzMUkcvXMQcnXRJ9A/viewform and https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pzPv4MAfmVxuQqsN5UrODXyLoF5LX7LoDoErOkigMXM/edit?usp=sharing
It's based off of this: https://developers.google.com/gsuite/solutions/content-signup

Answer (score -1):

Try to console.log(response) and observe if that have all properties you want.

Timestamp[0] is array?
And 'Email Addres' ?
The same for others properties.

You writed the error, but I think above this line error you can see exactly how property is undefined.

After mapping the correctly undefined property, you can debbug from request why returning undefined.